# 'Reduction' parameter in tf.keras.losses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction), the `Reduction` parameter takes on 3 values - `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`, `SUM` and `NONE`.

```
y_true = [[0., 2.], [0., 0.]]
y_pred = [[3., 1.], [2., 5.]]

mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
mae(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
> 5.5

mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
mae(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
> 2.75
```

What I could infer about the calculation after various trials, is this:-

- when `REDUCTION = SUM`,

  `Loss = Sum over all samples {(Sum of differences between y_pred and y_target vector of each sample / No of element in y_target of the sample )} = { (abs(3-0) + abs(1-2))/2 } + { (abs(2-0) + abs(5-0))/2 } = {4/2} + {7/2} = 5.5`.
- when `REDUCTION = SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`,

  `Loss = [Sum over all samples {(Sum of differences between y_pred and y_target vector of each sample / No of element in y_target of the sample )}] / Batch_size or No of Samples  = [ { (abs(3-0)} + abs(1-2))/2 } + { (abs(2-0) + abs(5-0))/2 } ]/2 = [ {4/2} + {7/2} ]/2 = [5.5]/2 = 2.75`.

As a result, `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` is nothing but `SUM/batch_size`. Then, why is it called `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` when `SUM` actually adds up the losses over the entire batch, while `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` calculates the average loss of the batch.

Is my assumption regarding the workings of `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` and `SUM` at all correct?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clearer. My question is if my assumption that "SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE" calculates the Average over the batch and not the sum is correct at all? Because, looking at the docs along with the PyTorch L1 loss (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.L1Loss.html#torch.nn.L1Loss), it seems that `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` corresponds to `mean` in Torch, and `SUM` corresponds to `sum`?

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from the ambiguous name. I originally assumed `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` meant that you are summing over all the examples in the batch. Instead, "over" in this case is used to mean "divided by" like how people might refer to 5/7 as five over seven. This certainly was not obvious to me originally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct as far as I understand.

If you check the github [keras/losses_utils.py][1] lines 260-269
you will see that it does performs as expected.
`SUM` will sum up the losses in the batch dimension, and `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` would divide `SUM` by the number of total losses (batch size).

```
def reduce_weighted_loss(weighted_losses,
                     reduction=ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE):
  if reduction == ReductionV2.NONE:
     loss = weighted_losses
  else:
     loss = tf.reduce_sum(weighted_losses)
     if reduction == ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE:
        loss = _safe_mean(loss, _num_elements(weighted_losses))
  return loss
```

You can do a easy checking with your previous example just by adding one pair of outputs with 0 loss.

```
y_true = [[0., 2.], [0., 0.],[1.,1.]]
y_pred = [[3., 1.], [2., 5.],[1.,1.]]

mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
mae(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
> 5.5

mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
mae(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
> 1.8333
```

So, your assumption is correct.
[1]: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/utils/losses_utils.py#L25-L84